# Sharing session attributes?

Tags: liferay, session-variables

I have two portlets in a liferay portal: an MVC portlet and a Vaadin portlet.

The first one sets a session attribute in this way:

```
long serviceId = 1;
PortletSession portSession = renderRequest.getPortletSession();
portSession.setAttribute("serviceId",   serviceId, PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

The second one reads it:

```
PortletRequest portletRequest = VaadinPortletService.getCurrentPortletRequest();
long serviceId = (long) portletRequest.getPortletSession().getAttribute("serviceId", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE)
```

The issue is that the session attribute read by the second portlet is null but not 1.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The private session attribute setting in the both portlets is false:
<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>

Answer (score 1):

Please add `<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>` in `liferay-portlet.xml` for both portlets.

The detail of this tag is this as per DTD:

> Element : private-session-attributes Set the
>   private-session-attributes value to true if the portlet does   not
>   share session attributes with the portal. The default value is   true.
>   The property "session.shared.attributes" in portal.properties
>   specifies which session attributes are shared even when the
>   private-session-attributes value is true.
>
> Data Type : #PCDATA

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
session.shared.attributes = Shared
```

in your liferay portal-ext.properties file.
All Variables which starts with the keyword 'Shared' will be application scoped.
If this is done, you no need to set

```
<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
```